# MYSQL SELECT how to know there's something selected or not

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $name WHERE date='$date'");
```

How to check whether anything selected or not.

i have tried these but of no use :
`if($result == NULL ){}`  , `if(!$result){}`

Help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
mysql_num_rows ($result);
```

to get the number of rows returned

```
if(!$result)
```

Will only tell wether the query executed or not

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of records by

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows > 0)
{
   //do something..
}
```